# PIC: What is the command sequence of sensor HTU21D to interface with PIC24FJ?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, sensor

-I have one PIC24FJ controller and one http://www.meas-spec.com/downloads/HTU21D.pdf Humidity/Temp. sensor .I want to take Humidity   from that.

-So When I show data sheet of sensor then its command sequences is on page-12 are very confusing.

-If anyone understanding that sequence then please help me.

Comment: Are you addressing the chip correctly via I²C (is it responding with ACKs)?  What commands have you tried, and what are the responses?

Comment: I am trying command which given in  page no.12 in data sheet.if you know how to write that command sequence then help me.

Comment: Maybe you should show some MINIMAL code with just the sequence you're using?

Comment: My sequency are `StartI2C1();MasterWriteI2C1(0x80);while(I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT);MasterWriteI2C1(0xF5);while(I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT);StartI2C1();MasterWriteI2C1(0x81);while(I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT == 0);StartI2C1();MasterWriteI2C1(0x81);while(I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT); hum_msb = MasterReadI2C1();AckI2C1();hum_lsb = MasterReadI2C1();AckI2C1();CRC = MasterReadI2C1();NotAckI2C1();`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the code.  It looks like you are on the right track for the most part.

After each command, you are waiting for an ACK by looking at the I2C1STATbits.ACKSTAT bit to go low.  However this bit indicates whether an ACK or a NACK was received, and you need to know that too.

So I think it is better to use the call IdleI2C1() after sending to the sensor, e.g.:

```
MasterWriteI2C1(0‌​xF5);
IdleI2C1();
```

(this is where you send the command from Table 9).  You can then check the ACKSTAT bit to see whether an ACK or NACK was was received.

After sending the command, in the No Hold Msteer mode for this chip, you need to be able to sense the NACK response, and loop until you get an ACK instead.  So instead of sending just the two read commands with address 0x81 as you are doing, you need to do something like this:

```
while (1)
{
    StartI2C1();
    MasterWriteI2C1(0x81);
    IdleI2C1();  
    if (I2C1STAT‌​bits.ACKSTAT == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

As long as you get a NACK back (I2C1STAT‌​bits.ACKSTAT == 1) then you loop around and try again.  Instead, if you get an ACK you can then read the two bytes of data plus the checksum as you are already doing.

You will probably want to add some sort of counter so you don't loop forever in case you never receive an ACK for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for another way.**But I am not getting any output from sensor.** Can you help more to solve my problem?